# Prove the intersection of decreasing nested sets is nonempty

Tags: real-analysis

Use the Heine-Borel theorem to prove that if $\{ F_n \} $ is a sequence of nonempty closed sets of real numbers such that $F_1$ is bounded and $F_{n+1} \subset F_n$ for every positive integer $n$ then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} F_n$ is not empty.

Since the sets are nested set of real numbers, this seems like an obvious fact, but I think my proof needs a lot of work.

Assume $\cap F_n$ is empty. For each $n$ let $U_n=\mathbb{R}\setminus F_n$.

Since $\cup U_n=\mathbb{R}\setminus \cap~ F_n$ that means $\cup~ U_n=\mathbb{R}$. The collection of $U_n$ makes up an open cover, so we can find a finite subcover. Take the largest set of that subcover and call it $A$ then $\mathbb{R} \subset A$ causing a contradiction.

Is this close?

Comment: This is exactly right.

Comment: Your proof works in a general setting of compact subsets in any metric or even topological space.

Comment: Is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty$ ( \sum_{n=1}^\infty ) supposed to be $\bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N}$ ( \bigcap_{n\in\Bbb N} )?